# Inequality for binomial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In a bombing attack there is $50\%$ chance that any bomb will hit the target. Two direct hits are required to destroy the target completely. How many bombs must be dropped to give a $99\%$ chance or better Of completely destroying the target target?

While solving I find this inequality....

$$
  (1/2^n)\times(n+1) <0.01
$$
What to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just for your curiosity.*

Sooner or later, you will learn that any equation which can write $$A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$$ has analytical solutions in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

This is the case for $$2^x=100\,(1+x)$$ (as A.E. wrote it) and the solution is given by $$x=-1-\frac{W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{200}\right)}{\log (2)}\approx 10.1188$$

More generally, the solution of $$a^x=k(1+x)$$ is given by $$x=-1-\frac{W\left(-\frac{\log (a)}{a k}\right)}{\log (a)}$$ where it could be the upper or lower branch of Lambert function as shown in the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

The binomial distribution can be approximated by the normal distribution.

$P(X>2)=1-\Phi\left( \frac{1+0.5-n\cdot 0.5}{\sqrt{0.5\cdot 0.5 \cdot n}}\right)\geq 0.99$

$\Phi\left( \frac{1+0.5-n\cdot 0.5}{\sqrt{0.5\cdot 0.5 \cdot n}}\right)\leq 0.01$

$\frac{1+0.5-n\cdot 0.5}{\sqrt{0.5\cdot 0.5 \cdot n}}\leq \Phi ^{-1}(0.01)$

$\frac{1+0.5-n\cdot 0.5}{\sqrt{0.5\cdot 0.5 \cdot n}}\leq -2.326$

$1.5-n\cdot 0.5\leq -2.326\cdot \sqrt{0.25 \cdot n}$

Squaring the equation on both sides. Squaring an inequality is not an equivalent transormation. We can transform into an equality and round up one of the two solutions at the end.

$0.25n^2-1.5n+2.25= -2.326^2\cdot 0.25\cdot n$

$0.25n^2+(-2.326^2\cdot 0.25-1.5)n+2.25=0$

Solving for $n$ gives $n_1=10.56$ and $n_2=0.85$. The final solution is $n^*=11$

Now you can check with your inequality if the solution is right.

For $n=10$ we get $0.5^{10}\cdot 11=1.04\%>1\%$

For $n=11$ we get $0.5^{11}\cdot 12=0.59\%<1\% \quad \color{blue}{\checkmark}$

Thus $n^*=11$ is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the strikes are mutually independent. Each strike $X_i$ is a Bernoulli trial with $p=1/2$. Hence  let $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ be the total number of on-target hits.  Clearly, $X_n \sim Bin(n,p)$.

Therefore, 
$$
P(X_n \ge 2) > 0.99
$$ 
$$
P(X_n \ge 2 ) = 1- P(X_n <2) = 1-\frac{1}{2^n} - n\times\frac{1}{2^n}>0.99,
$$
thus
$$
2^n>100(1+n).
$$
Numerically and intuitively, you are interested in the intersection of two function: $2^x$ and $100(1+x)$. At first glance I don't see a simple analytical method to find it, hence, like was shown by @callculus you can use the normal approximation to the binomial distribution (just check, a-posteriori in this case,  for the thumb rules of $np \ge 5$ and $nq\ge 5$). However, in this case it is easy to solve it numerically as $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $100(1+n)$ is linear function that increases in a much more slow rate then the exponential $2^n$.  So it is easy to see (by plugging some reasonable values of $n$) that the first positive integer value that satisfies the inequality is indeed $11$.